# Django aggregation across multiple tables in ModelAdmin queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

### Django Code & Reference to Django Bug Report

Given three models as follows (simplified excessively for demonstration...not actually identical related models)

```
class derp(models.Model):
    ...
class derp_related_1(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(derp)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
class derp_related_2(models.Model):
    fk = models.ForeignKey(derp)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
```

And overriding a queryset in the model admin as follows. (It isn't working because of [this django bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060).)

```
class DerpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ['derp_r1_sum', 'derp_r2_sum']
    ...
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(DerpAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.annotate(derp_r1_sum=models.Sum('derp_r1__amount', distinct=True))
        qs = qs.annotate(derp_r2_sum=models.Sum('derp_r2__amount', distinct=True))
    def derp_r1_sum(self, obj):
        return u'%s' % obj.derp_r1_sum
    def derp_r2_sum(self, obj):
        return u'%s' % obj.derp_r2_sum
```

### Example of Unexpected Database Result

Running annotations individually would render something like (with grouping & sums removed)

```
+---------+--------+
| derp.id | r1_sum |
+---------+--------+
|       2 | 500.00 |
|       2 | 100.00 |
+---------+--------+
r1_sum would be 600.00
and
+---------+--------+
| derp.id | r1_sum |
+---------+--------+
|       2 | 100.00 |
|       2 | 250.00 |
+---------+--------+
r2_sum would be 350.00
```

If you take qs.query with both annotations included and remove the sums and the grouping it is obvious what the problem is. In this case we're counting everything twice. Get more relations and we have an increasingly ugly increase in both sum columns.

```
+---------+--------+--------+
| derp.id | r1_sum | r2_sum |
+---------+--------+--------+
|       2 | 500.00 | 100.00 |
|       2 | 500.00 | 250.00 |
|       2 | 100.00 | 100.00 |
|       2 | 100.00 | 250.00 |
+---------+--------+--------+
r1_sum would incorrectly be 1200.00
r2_sum would incorrectly be 700.00
```

### Question, is there a route other than custom SQL?

I can write the query myself easy enough, but if anyone has a suggestion which would avoid the writing of custom SQL that would be awesome.

Thanks for the help.

**Edit:** Here is a link to the annotations section of the Django documentation. One commenter mentioned the distinct option. This does not work, and I believe it is what is warned about at the bottom of the annotation section in the [django documentation on annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values).

**Edit2:** The raw SQL idea likely is more difficult than I thought as derp.objects.raw('sql here') does not return the queryset object necessary for the admin to use it. Is there a way to use two queries (the real queryset plus a custom one doing the sums) and populate the listview from both? One suggestion I found (which I cannot find again now :S) suggested creating a view that maps to a Model definition which is then set to unmanaged by django (for syncdb). I could then write my custom code, and reference it for inclusion in the original query. This sounds messy. Thoughts?

Comment: "Sum" doesn't seem to have a "distinct" keyword argument no ?

Comment: @Ricola3D distinct doesn't do any good if you're joining to multiple relations. I did try that initially, but it changes nothing. The distinct would be added per individual Sum, and therefore the multiplication effect would still happen. I believe https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values the very bottom warning there describes what I am experiencing. I'm just looking to see if I should write the SQL myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to return the correct results was by using `queryset.extra()`.

```
derp_r1_sum_select = """
    select sum(`derp_related_1`.`amount`)
    from `derp_related_1` 
    where `derp_related_1`.`fk` = `derp`.`pk`
    """
derp_r2_sum_select = """
    select sum(`derp_related_2`.`amount`)
    from `derp_related_2`
    where `derp_related_2`.`fk` = `derp`.`pk`"
    """

def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(DerpAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        qs = qs.extra(select={'derp_r1_sum': derp_r1_sum_select,
                              'derp_r2_sum': derp_r2_sum_select})
        return qs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay within Django's queryset, I would consider creating a model superclass that shares the related and common fields and sub-classing for further distinctions. Otherwise, you need to either write custom SQL or get out of the database ORM entirely and manipulate your data in python with `Queryset.values` or `Queryset.values_list`